# Why they pronounce 'Shehab', 'Shebab'?

Tags: pronunciation, names

My name, Shehab, is an Arabic word. Interesting, more than 10 white Americans and a black American have addressed me 'Shebab' (both in writing and verbally).

Why is this particular mistake is so much common?

Comment: Interesting as the question is, i don't think it's to do with the English language, and so not really on topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about the English language.

Comment: Well, there *are* people named *Shebib* or *Shebab*, at least as a surname, so perhaps it is as simple as confusing *David* and *Davis*. Perhaps their minds drifted to [doo-wop](http://www.shsu.edu/lis_fwh/book/roots_of_rock/Doo-Wop2.htm) lyrics (*bomp she bomp*), or conflated it with Turkish *shishkebab*. It's rare for *she-*  to be followed with *-h* in English, and perhaps their tongue simply drifts. There might be a dozen other explanations, but any answer we give can only be speculative.

Answer (score 2):

Some typefaces (including the one on this SE) use [serifs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serif), which can make it quite difficult to see the difference between lowercase "B" and "H", especially if the letters are shown small on paper or a computer screen